# How to speed up `DataFrame.drop_duplicates()`?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a function which calls `df.drop_duplciates(subset = ["Column"], keep = 'last')` method multiple times which takes a lot of time. How can I speed up this process? What is the other, faster way to remove duplicated rows from `DataFrame` by a given column(s) and keep the last one?

Comment: Set a boolean flag on each row you want to remove and at the end of your process remove them. You can use `duplicated` instead of `drop_duplicates` to get this.

Comment: check out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54196959/is-there-any-faster-alternative-to-col-drop-duplicates for some suggestions